# Counting digits in a number without using strings

Tags: c++, string, parsing, numbers, digits

i have the next code which asks the user for a really long number like 100000000 and then it prints how many times a given digit appears on that number, the code works fine and does everything correctly, but the professor told me that i dont have to use strings or chars, but when the code asks the user for a number it necessarily needs a string and i don´t know how to modify it, i used the gmp library

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#define MAX 40

using namespace std;

void searchDigit(FILE *fd);
int NewNumber();

int main()
{
    FILE *fd;
    int otherNumber;
    string text;
    mpz_t num;
    do
    {
        if((fd = fopen("File.txt","w+"))!= NULL)
        {
            mpz_init(num);
            cout << "Give me the number: " << endl;
            cin >> text;
            mpz_set_str(num,text.c_str(),10);
            mpz_out_str(fd,10,num);
            fclose(fd);
            searchDigit(fd);
            otherNumber = NewNumber();
        }
        else
           cout << "Fail!!" << endl;
    }while(otherNumber);
    return 0;
}

void searchDigit(FILE *fd)
{
    int car,continue = 1,r;
    char answer,digit;
    if((fd = fopen("File.txt","r"))!= NULL)
    {
        do
        {
            r = 0;
            fseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);
            cout << "What digit do you want to search? " << endl;
            cin >> digit;
            while((car = fgetc(fd))!= EOF)
            {
                if(car == digit)
                   r++;
            }
            cout << "The digit x=" <<digit<< " appears " << r << " times" << endl;
            cout << "Do you want to search any other digit? " << endl;
            cin >> answer;
            if(answer != 'S')
               continue = 0;
        }while(continue);
    }
    else
       cout << "Fail!!" << endl;
}

int NewNumber()
{
    char answer;
    cout << "DO you wish to work with a new number? " << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer == 'S' || answer == 's')
       return 1;
    else
       return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do bitwise operations.

Comment: `continue` is a C++ keyword. How does that even compile??

Comment: thanks for your answers, @adifire what do you mean with bitwise operations?, how could i use them in my code

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how big your input might actually be... but for retrieving digits you could do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long UINT64;

int main() {
    UINT64 i;
    std::cin >> i;
    while (i >= 1) {
        int digit = i % 10;
        std::cout << digit << " ";
        i /= 10;
    }
}
```

input: `18446744073709551614`

outputs: `4 1 6 1 5 5 9 0 7 3 7 0 4 4 7 6 4 4 8 1`